# Backup Exec - One backup to two locations

Tags: windows, backupexec

We are running Backup Exec 11d (I know, I know... next year's budget).

We'd like to set up backups to go to the current backup server, which hosts a tape drive, and to a remote server which has a large RAID we've set up as our "off-site" backup.

The plan is to send our tapes weekly, and do a nightly differential over the fiber to the RAID.

What's the best way to configure backup exec for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate backup sets
http://seer.entsupport.symantec.com/docs/299213.htm

Comment: http://seer.entsupport.symantec.com/docs/284575.htm would be the proper link for your answer